# Loop generates Multiple selects - how to remeber posted data on each selected option with php

Tags: php, forms, post

I have this loop which generates selects:

```
$loops=7;    
//for($j=1;$j<=$loops;$j++){
foreach($_SESSION['product'] as $key=>$val){    
$quantity = 7;    
$selqty = '<div class="optchk"><select name="qty[]" class="qty">';    
for($i=1;$i<=$quantity;$i++){    
$selqty.='<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';    

}
$selqty.='</select></div>';
}
echo '<form method="post" action="" name="orderform">';    
echo $selqty;
echo '<input type="submit" name="order_submit" value="Send"></form>';
```

How to keep each selected option for all those 7 selects after form submit?
Thank you

post looks like :

```
array(7) { 
[0]=> string(1) "2" 
[1]=> string(1) "3" 
[2]=> string(1) "4" 
[3]=> string(1) "4" 
[4]=> string(1) "2" 
[5]=> string(1) "3" 
[6]=> string(1) "4"
}
```

and I tried the following :

```
<?php if($_POST['qty'] =$i) $selected= 'selected=selected';
$selqty.='<option '.$selected.' value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
?>
```

but it is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `action = ""` you can check the values of `qty[]` and select the corresponding value for each select. Here is a working code:

```
$loops=7; 
$selqty = "";
$j = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['product'] as $key=>$val)
{    
    $j++;
$quantity = 7;    
$selqty .= '<div class="optchk"><select name="qty[]" class="qty">';    
for($i=1;$i<=$quantity;$i++)
{    
    $selected = "";
    if(isset($_POST['qty']) && $i == $_POST['qty'][$j-1])
        $selected = "selected";

    $selqty.='<option value="'.$i.'"'.$selected.'>'.$i.'</option>';    
}
$selqty.='</select></div>';
}
echo '<form method="post" action="" name="orderform">';    
echo $selqty;
echo '<input type="submit" name="order_submit" value="Send"></form>';
```

I also recommend you to get used to using double quotes when inserting php variables into strings:

You can use

```
$selqty.="<option value='$i' $selected> $i </option>";
```

insetad of

```
$selqty.='<option value="'.$i.'"'.$selected.'>'.$i.'</option>';
```

Which I think is easier to read and understand.

Comment: Alvaro, first of all thank you for helping me. I will take your notices ! Also since the example I showed above is not really equal to the real code because it was hard for me to prepare an example and that's why instead of the real loop foreach($_SESSION['product'] as $key=>$val){ which I just replaced I showed "for"  loop and now I can not test your code because of this line: if(isset($_POST['qty']) && $i == $_POST['qty'][$j-1])
How would this line look like with the new loop foreach($_SESSION['product'] as $key=>$val){ ?
Sorry about this but I didn't realize it will reflects the answer..

Comment: Alvaro, I suppose the new line must look like:
if(isset($_POST['qty']) && $i == $_POST['qty'][$key]) $selected = "selected";
correct? - thank you :)

Comment: @thecore7 That should probably work. But as I don´t know the structure of the `$_SESSION['product']` array y edited the answer for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the page after the submit with the parameters from the form data, just see if its selected in the data you got and generate the appropriate html for it

Comment: Dima the problem is that I have this post: array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(1) "4" [3]=> string(1) "4" [4]=> string(1) "2" [5]=> string(1) "3" [6]=> string(1) "4"} and don't know how to recognize which value for which select it is